# Divisible Groups $G$ and $G/H$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a group, $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$. We say that $G$ is divisible, if for every $x \in G$ and $n$ is a positive integer, there is $y \in G$ such that $y^n=x$.

Show that if $G$ is divisible, then so is $G/H$

Not sure how to start on this off. Any hints and suggestions would be helpful!

Comment: Well let $x$ be an element of $G/H$, what can you say about $x$?

Comment: if x is an element of G/H, then there is xH such that x is in G.

Comment: Okay so let's refer to the element $xH$ of $G/ H$ as $[x]$. We want yo prove that there is $[y] = yH$ in $G / H$ such that $[y]^n = [x]$. What would this mean in terms of $x$ and $y$ rather than $[x]$ and $[y]$?

Comment: That would mean that y^nH^n=xH, so n multiples of a left coset of H in G is equal to another left coset of H in G.

Comment: And what is $H^n$?

Answer (score 2):

You're being misled by details. Consider a more general statement:

> Let $f\colon G\to G'$ be a surjective group homomorphism. If $G$ is a divisible group, then also $G'$ is divisible.

Proof. Let $a\in G'$ and let $n$ be a positive integer. Since $f$ is surjective, there exists $x\in G$ with $f(x)=a$. Since $G$ is divisible, there exists $y\in G$ with $y^n=x$.

> Set $b=f(y)$; then $b^n=a$

Then you have the answer: you do know a surjective homomorphism $G\to G/H$, don't you?

Answer (score 0):

You must consider the class aritmethic, by the notation I suppose that your group is multiplicative, then $G/H=\left\{gH:g\in G\right\}$ thus, the aritmethic of the quotient group should be $(g_1H)(g_2H)=g_1g_2H$. Take $xH\in G/H$ and $n\in\mathbb{N}$, since $x\in G$ and $G$ is divisible there exists $y\in G$ that $y^n=x$, consider now $yH\in G/H$ since $H$ is normal the multiplication is commutative then $(yH)^n=y^nH=xH$ by the arguments above. So the problem is solved.